# how to use removeObjectsInArray in swift

Tags: swift

I have two arrays

```
var availableIndex: Int[] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
var answerIndex: Int[] = [1, 3, 10, 8]
```

I want to remove 1, 3, 10, 8 from availableIndex array. I've seen the documentation how to achieve that using [removeObjectsInArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSMutableOrderedSet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableOrderedSet/removeObjectAtIndex%3a)

```
availableIndex.removeObjectsInArray(answerIndex)
```

but I can't use that method, it gave me an error. I have no idea where's my fault. Sorry if my bad English

edit:

here is the error 'Int[]' does not have a member named 'removeObjectsInArray'

Comment: Could you include the error you receive?

Comment: I've just edited my question. thanks for your help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The proper Swifty way to do this is

```
availableIndex = availableIndex.filter { value in
   !answerIndex.contains(value)
}
```

(will create a new filtered array only with values not contained in `answerIndex`)

Of course, a better solution would be to convert `answerIndex` into a `Set`.

`removeObjectsInArray` is defined only on Obj-C mutable arrays (`NSMutableArray`).

An Obj-C workaround is to define the array directly as `NSMutableArray`

```
var availableIndex: NSMutableArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
var answerIndex: Int[] = [1, 3, 10, 8]

availableIndex.removeObjectsInArray(answerIndex)
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your time to answer my question. it works. thank you very much

Comment: Hi! That does not seem to work for me ... Should the content of the array to remove be of a particular type, or respond to a specific protocol ?

Comment: Found it: it has to respond to protocol Equatable

Comment: .filter{} works too slow than .removeObjectsInArray !?

Comment: Is there a performance difference between the swifty way and tje ObjC method?

Comment: @Fr4nc3sc0NL There probably is some difference because the underlaying algorithm is very different. I would guess the Swift way is a bit better but that's just a guess. You should not worry about it because it won't probably affect you. If you have peformance problems, start by converting `answerIndex` into a `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to do it like that:

```
availableIndex.removeAll(where: { answerIndex.contains($0) })
```